# Java: How to extract date from the string

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I am building groovy test and have the `String` in Properties:

```
date = new Date("09/15/2016")
```

Need to extract the `String` part with date like:

```
y=09/15/2016
```

I tried with `substring` method and it works but what if I want to use other methods like Regular expression or DateFormat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far and what didn't work.

Comment: Don't do it with a regular expression, there are tools for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've tagged this groovy, you can also do:

```
Date date = Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "09/15/2016")
```

#### Update:

Ok...Weird...  I didn't understand you actually had `new Date(blah)` as a String

This should work then, guess you *do* need a regexp ;-)

```
String weirdDateString = 'new Date("09/15/2016")'

String extractedDate = weirdDateString.find(/[0-9\/]+/)

Date date = Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', extractedDate)
```

Comment: Nope, the question is that at first Properies variable  gets full string like "new Date('09/15/2016')". So I need parse this string to get substring 09/15/2016'

Comment: @OlegVetrov Updated my answer...  Weird properties file...  Who did that?

Comment: Thank you very match, friend!

Comment: In fact, a script sets those Property before Jenkins starts auto test. We need it to change current date in application.

Comment: @OlegVetrov No worries, you can click the tick next to this answer if it solves your problem :-)  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
        Date date = new Date("09/15/2016");
        String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);
```